# need to understand shell awk code

Tags: shell, printing, awk

i am stumbling on this code, i am trying to parse the file by the separator ";" and save it into other new file. but now it is saving the original content into new file wihtout separating.

```
cat $file | awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}{ print  > "final.txt"}END{ print "parsed now..."}'
```

but it is giving me the original file content. i thought, `print` will print the all columns of the file which is processed by awk.

can someone please help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: Still did not understand what exactly are you looking for.Make your question more clear if possible with an example of input and output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the problem is that you don't get output where ";" should be substituted by " " (which is standard OFS)?
If that's the problem why not do

```
sed 's/;/ /g' $file
```

Anyway - AFAIK `print` in awk means `print $0` where `$0` is just the input line. If no fields in that line changed explicitly `$0` is not updated at all. My workaround usually is to make a pseudo-update `$1=$1` to enforce updating `$0`. Maybe there's a "cleaner" way...

```
cat $file | awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}{$1=$1;print  > "final.txt"}END{ print "parsed now..."}'
```

**EDIT:**

```
awk -F";" '{print $4}' $file >final.txt
```

Comment: thanks man, how do i print the 4th column then? can you please explain me this logic of how to print which column....

Comment: You should also fix the Useless Use of Cat. See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 0):

Print will by default print $0 which is the complete line.
so whatever you are getting is correct.

May i know wht exactly do you need?
do u need the separator to be removed?

4th column can be printed with below:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"}{ print $4 > "final.txt"}END{ print "parsed now..."}' $file
```

Comment: thanks, what i really need is that i have a big file containing some information, and in every 50th line, there is a ; and i want to parse the whole file into particles, in this case columns if i understand the logic of awk right.